# In Jenkins how to extract Payload from Bitbucket webhook

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, payload, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-webhook

In jenkins pipeline and in a multibranch job, how to extract the payload sent with the webhook that is created automatically through bitbucket server integration plugin.

I found a solution for generic webhook which is by post parameters in jenkins and defining the payload variable name, then using it directly in the pipeline

But I couldn't find a solution for how it works when it comes to bitbucket server integration webhook